# Unable to create backup for database

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup, database-backups

I am unable to create a database backup, as the user which I login is not a superuser and it doesn't have all privileges.

How can I create a user that has all permissions over the databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below script to create a login with sysadmin permission for all databases. Replace 'test' with your username.

```
 USE [master]
 GO
 CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'test', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
 GO
 EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'test', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
 GO
```

Then create your backup..